# Use a preferred username but authenticate against Kerberos principal

Tags: kerberos

What I desire to do should be pretty simple.

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 box. It's currently configured to authenticate users against a kerberos realm (EXAMPLE.ORG). There is only one realm in the krb5.conf file and it is the default realm.

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXAMPLE.ORG
```

PAM is configured to use the pam_krb5 module, so if a user account is created on the local machine, and that username matches the username@EXAMPLE.ORG credential, that user may log in by supplying his kerberos password.

What I would like to do instead is create a local user account with a *different* username, but have it always authenticate against the canonical name in the kerberos server.

For example, the kerberos principal is `full.name@EXAMPLE.ORG`. I would like to create the local account `preferred.name` and somehow configure kerberos that when someone attempts to log in as `preferred.name`, it uses the principal `full.name@EXAMPLE.ORG`.

I have tried using the `auth_to_local_names` in krb5.conf, but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
[realms]
    EXAMPLE.ORG = {
            auth_to_local_names = {
                    full.name = preferred.name
            }
```

I have tried adding `full.name@EXAMPLE.ORG` to ~preferred.name/.k5login.

In all cases, when I attempt to log in as preferred.name@host and enter the password for full.name, I get Access denied.

I even tried using `auth_to_local` in krb5.conf, but I couldn't get the syntax right.

Is it possible to have a (distinct) local username that for all purposes behaves exactly like a matching username does? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't need to use auth_to_local at all. I could use .k5login in the user's home directory. First,

```
cat > ~preferred.name/.k5login
full.name@EXAMPLE.ORG
```

Then, I had to configure PAM to honor the .k5login. In /etc/pam.d/common-auth, where I find `auth sufficient pam_krb5.so`, append the option `search_k5login`.

Thereafter, any attempt to log in as preferred.name will accept the password for full.name@EXAMPLE.ORG.

Comment: that's awesome. Is it possible to do the same using just settings in krb5.conf? thanks.

Comment: @Ruslan I don't know. I haven't tried. Let us know what you find.